# call function on text field change

Tags: swift, function, call, nstextfield

I want to call a function when a text field text is edited in any way.

im new to swift and code-walls don't really help me understand and thats all I've been able to find searching for an answer.

some one showed themselves ctrl-clicking on the text field and showing a sent action by the name of 'editing did start' or something like that but I only have sent action called 'action'. I need clarification.

EDIT: this is for a MacOS application, UIKit doesn't work.

```
import Cocoa

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate, NSTextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!
    @IBOutlet weak var msgBox: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var keyBox: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var encBtn: NSButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var decBtn: NSButton!
    override func controlTextDidChange(_ obj: Notification) {
        //makeKey()
        keyBox.stringValue = "test"
    }

    override func controlTextDidBeginEditing(_ obj: Notification) {
        print("Did begin editing...")
    }

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Insert code here to initialize your application
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Insert code here to tear down your application
    }

    func makeKey() {
        keyBox.stringValue = "test"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On macOS, you have similar to iOS, `NSTextFieldDelegate`.

Steps are:

1) Drag-n-drop `NSTextField` instance onto your window.

2) Set its delegate to your `NSViewController`:

[image: Setting up delegate]

3) Make your `ViewController` (or any other managing class) implement `NSTextFieldDelegate`, and implement any of the needed text-change related actions:

```
class ViewController: NSViewController, NSTextFieldDelegate {

    // Occurs whenever there's any input in the field
    override func controlTextDidChange(_ obj: Notification) {
        let textField = obj.object as! NSTextField
        print("Change occured. \(textField.stringValue)")
    }

    // Occurs whenever you input first symbol after focus is here
    override func controlTextDidBeginEditing(_ obj: Notification) {
        let textField = obj.object as! NSTextField
        print("Did begin editing... \(textField.stringValue)")
    }

    // Occurs whenever you leave text field (focus lost)
    override func controlTextDidEndEditing(_ obj: Notification) {
        let textField = obj.object as! NSTextField
        print("Ended editing... \(textField.stringValue)")
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the code of your ViewController, which handles NSTextField events.

Comment: Glad it worked. I must note, however, that having regular outlets (buttons, textfields) and other view-related stuff in AppDelegate is a bad practice. Good way is to leave it in dedicated ViewController, responsible for that particular screen (window). Otherwise AppDelegate will eventually burst. It should only be responsible for application workflow things and not break the [single responsibility principle](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L2m-S0Pj_Xk).